# Combining a IN and AND query

Tags: mysql, sql

My db table is as follows

testTable

```
|-----|-------------------|
  Id     comment
   2  | 20 degree celsius
   3  | 30 degree Farenheit
   4  | 40 degree Farenheit
   5  | sometime 
   6  | plain text
   7  | plain text
   8  | plain text
```

I want to query the db to get all the ids where string contains celsius or farenheit

Query :

```
SELECT Id FROM testTable where id in (2,3,4) 
AND comment like '%celsius%' or comment like '%Farenheit%'
```

but this query checks for all the ids not the id I provide in the in condition ?
How to query for only the id in the in Condition ?

Comment: how did you know that this query checks for all the ids? because i tried with "explain". I haven't got a clue.

Comment: the above query returns all ids which have the particular sting not the id in the in condition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use brackets like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM testTable where id in (2,3,4) 
AND 
(comment like '%celsius%' or comment like '%Farenheit%')
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a05e4/1)